# Trying to draw shortest path lines in visio. Advice please?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013, microsoft-visio-2010

I am trying to make network diagrams and connect devices with lines but want them

1. to be orthogonal - horizontal and vertical lines only
2. shortest path.

If I have 2 ports at the same vertical position and draw a line between them, snap to center, the resulting line will not be a single straight horizontal line, but one that goes down a bit then comes back up - 3 or more segments.  I can manually move the lower segment up to be a single line, but that's tedious. The same happens in other situations. I can see a more direct path than Visio does.

These are not complex drawings. Think a home network - a 4 port router, and 4 devices.

Comment: An example image would be nice.

Comment: I will place 2 devices and draw a connecting line to the them (see drawing 1). 

Then my OCD wants the line to have minimal lines so I highlight the 2 squares and choose align center or manually move 1 device so the 2 boxes are at the same height. At that point, rather than the straignt line I want and get AFTER Visio muddies things (see drawing 3) I get that 2 hop line with turns (see drawing 2).  This ir routine.  KInda like Visio doesn't want to draw a 0 deg. line between 2 boxes that are at the same height?

now how do I attach the drawings?!

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fqvp02erds1gaat/AACnpIb3enU276CiUxcxuvnBa?dl=0

Comment: And I just tried - aligning the 2 boxes, THEN draw the line... it still does something like drawing 2.  It would rather hop across other lines than make the down lines shorter (or go up and not have to jump) or just go straight across.  The centers of those 2 squares ARE at the same Y measurement.

Comment: I see similar behavior only when connector is bound to a center of a shape. Have you tried to bound it to an edge?

Comment: Interesting!  I hadn't tried binding to an edge.  For my OCD, I have to think if that looks as good / conveys info to insert the wire in that port.  I DO know that binding to the center annoys me because sometimes it makes it hard to read the port number that's in the center : )